# How can I access the USB drive my Live Linux is running on?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, liveusb

I'm completely new to Linux. I've downloaded Ubuntu, then using a Linux Live CD, I've created a bootable USB drive.

Ubuntu works beautifully on the USB boot. However, while I can read the hard disks on my machine, I cannot seem to detect the USB itself, i.e. the one on which this Linux is installed.

Of course I am dead sure the USB is plugged in as I am physically in front of the machine.

How do I detect / locate my USB? How do I download stuff to my USB?